# Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, python-2.7, java-native-interface

I am trying to call python script from Java. Python version is 2.7.8

```
    // set up the command and parameter
    String pythonScriptPath = "C://Python27//ArcGIS10.3//helloPython.py";
    String[] cmd = new String[2];
    cmd[0] = "python";
    cmd[1] = pythonScriptPath;

    // create runtime to execute external command
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = rt.exec(cmd);
```

where path of python.exe is C://Python27//ArcGIS10.3// which is already stored as path variable in windows still last line giving me above exception. I checked other solutions but didn't seem to work. Can you please help me resolving issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a windows user, but I would imagine the "//" are backwards. Try "\\" instead.